# SSL error when downloading composer on mac

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I'm bit of a newb in macOS and I'm struggling to install composer on my macOS system. Whenever I try to execute

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

in my terminal from [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/), I'm getting this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA7d5.png).

I tried to ask google, but there was no success for me.

If you can help me with this I would be very grateful. Also sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: He can't verify the certificate. Have you set the correct date on the machine?

Comment: Yeah, I let my machine set the time automatically, and It has been set correctly.

Comment: Can you visit the website in your browser without any problems relating to the certificate?

Comment: You mean composer website ? Yeah, I can, everthing works fine there.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3346#issuecomment-765937‌​63

Comment: Download https://getcomposer.org/download/1.2.1/composer.phar and follow the link https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the composer phar from directly https://getcomposer.org/download/1.2.1/composer.phar and now just run `php composer.phar` in order to run Composer.
If you want it globally ,follow the link https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

> Note: If the above fails due to permissions, you may need to run it
>   again with sudo.
>
> Note: On some versions of OSX the /usr directory does not exist by
>   default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such
>   file or directory" then you must create the directory manually before
>   proceeding: mkdir -p /usr/local/bin.

Now just run composer in order to run Composer instead of `php composer.phar`.